# Oracle Exchange partition from non partitioned table

Tags: oracle

We have table name **Summary** with 86 GB data. This table do not have **partition/sub-partition** .We want to move the data from the summary table to a **composite partitioned table** (**range partition on entry_date column** and **hash partition on users_codes column** ) .

> oracle doesn't allow to exchange data with non partitioned table

So we are doing the following approach.kindly let me know if this is correct approach.

1. Create a temporary table **summary_temp** with **range partition on entry_date** column ,then exchange the data from **summary** table to partitioned table(summary_temp) in **part_hist**.
2. Alter the **summary_temp** table to add sub partition (**hash partition on users_codes**) column
3. exchange the partition and sub_partition data to the another empty destination table which is having the same partition and sub partition.

Answer (score 3):

We have done the same operation using the following approach:

1. Create the destination table with the correct structure nologging
2. Insert append parallel into it (verifiy direct path load in the explain plan)
3. Create the indexes nologging
4. in some case add the FK novalidate
5. compute the stats
6. Alter the objects LOGGING
7. Drop the initial table

Comment: Good list -- could combine 1 & 2, or could consider creating the indexes prior to the insert *if* they are few in number and the total size of indexed column data is small relative to total size of table data.

Comment: Yes, it could be combined using a CTAS but you will loose the exact defintion of columns (NUMBER(8)=>NUMBER)